# how to use formik setValues

Tags: reactjs, formik, tsx

the initial values are all undefined and i dont know how to change them trough setValues

initialValues={{
birth_date: undefined,
gen_id: undefined,
state: undefined,
city: undefined,
mar_id: undefined,
lic_id: undefined,
}}

```
    setValues({...values, gen_id: events.target.name})
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.